# Sort Array Based Off Another Array Sorted By Date

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I found online how to sort an array based off another array and it works flawlessly

```
let english = ["June 12, 2019", "August 12, 2018", "June 1, 2018", "July 18, 2018", "May 4, 2018"]
let ints = [3, 5, 4, 1, 2]
let doubles = [3.0, 5.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0]
let roman = ["III", "V", "IV", "I", "II"]

let offsets = english.enumerated().sorted { $0.element < $1.element }.map { $0.offset }

let sorted_english = offsets.map { english[$0] }
let sorted_ints = offsets.map { ints[$0] }
let sorted_doubles = offsets.map { doubles[$0] }
let sorted_roman = offsets.map { roman[$0] }

print(sorted_english)
print(sorted_ints)
print(sorted_doubles)
print(sorted_roman)
```

It prints the following

```
["August 12, 2018", "July 18, 2018", "June 1, 2018", "June 12, 2019", "May 4, 2018"]
[5, 1, 4, 3, 2]
[5.0, 1.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0]
["V", "I", "IV", "III", "II"]
```

The `english` array is sorted by alphabetically. I want to sort that array by date. Here is the code I have that will do that

```
let formatter : DateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    df.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    return df
}()
let sortedMonthArray = english.sorted( by: { formatter2.date(from: $0)! < formatter2.date(from: $1)! })
```

How can I sort the other arrays based on the `sortedMonthArray`?

Comment: Is this just an exercise or do you have a real need for this? I ask because you should only have one array containing a struct. And your dates should be `Date`, not `String`.

Comment: No it's not an exercise. I'm making an app, and this is the last piece that I need.There is a reason that my dates are strings at this point in my project, but it would take to long to explain.

Comment: Dates should be `Date`. The only time they should be a string is to display it to the user.

Comment: Converting date strings to dates is a fairly expensive operation. The best sorting algorithms take n • log(n) time. By converting your date strings to dates in the sort, you are adding 2 • n • log(n) date-to-string conversions to your sort operation, which will slow it down signficantly. rmaddy is right on both counts. Convert this to a single array of structs, and store the dates as Date objects. Date Objects **and** date strings, if you must, but don't try to sort date strings by converting them to `Date` objects on each comparison.

Comment: I just ran a test. Sorting an array of 10,000 Date objects took ≈0.012 seconds. Sorting an array of 10,000 date strings as you do above by converting each date in the body of the sort function took ≈14.497 seconds, or ≈1177 times longer. Yes, over a thousand times longer. sorting an array of 100,000 date strings takes so long that I gave up on it. (Ok, I ran it. It took over 3 minutes, or  about 1287 times longer than sorting the same-sized array of Date objects. The longer the array, the more the date string sort lags behind the Date sort.

Comment: I don't think the array would ever get that high. Its only adding months of a year. There's 12 months in a year, and if we use the app for 30 years it's only 360 date strings. So, I'm not even really worried about that. It would only take 0.626 seconds.

Comment: @Duncan C I get the point you are trying to make though and I appreciate your time, but there is a reason that it's a date string. I probably could convert it to a Date, but then I would just have to convert it right back to a string after this which would take more time.

Comment: But the point is that when you sort an array of date strings and convert from strings to dates in the sort closure, you convert the same date strings to dates over and over and over. You want an array of structs that contains everything, and your dates as both strings and as `Date` objects. Then sort based on the Date field and all the other fields "come along for the ride."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the correct `date` `format` to get formatted dates. The rest can be done as below,

```
    let english = ["June 12, 2019", "August 12, 2018", "June 1, 2018", "July 18, 2018", "May 4, 2018"]
    let ints = [3, 5, 4, 1, 2]
    let doubles = [3.0, 5.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0]
    let roman = ["III", "V", "IV", "I", "II"]

    let formatter : DateFormatter = {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        df.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
        return df
    }()

    let dates = english.map({ formatter.date(from: $0) })
    let offsets = dates.enumerated().sorted( by: { $0.element! < $1.element! }).map({ $0.offset})

    let sorted_english = offsets.map { english[$0] }
    let sorted_ints    = offsets.map { ints[$0] }
    let sorted_doubles = offsets.map { doubles[$0] }
    let sorted_roman   = offsets.map { roman[$0] }

    print(sorted_english)
    print(sorted_ints)
    print(sorted_doubles)
    print(sorted_roman)
```

**Output:**

```
["May 4, 2018", "June 1, 2018", "July 18, 2018", "August 12, 2018", "June 12, 2019"]
[2, 4, 1, 5, 3]
[2.0, 4.0, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0]
["II", "IV", "I", "V", "III"]
```

---

**Suggestion:**

The above approach is cumbersome enough to suggest you a better design.

Create a `struct` that has all the associated members as below,

```
struct MyStruct {

    // MARK: - Private properties
    private var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        df.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
        return df
    }()

    // MARK: - Public properties
    public var date: Date!
    public var index: Int = 0
    public var value: Double = 0.0
    public var roman: String
    public var dateString: String

    // MARK: - Initialization
    init(_ dateString: String, index: Int, value: Double, roman: String) {
        self.dateString = dateString
        self.index = index
        self.value = value
        self.roman = roman
        self.date = self.dateFormatter.date(from: self.dateString)
    }
}
```

Now you can create a single `array` of `MyStruct` as below and sort with date,

```
    let data = [
        MyStruct("June 12, 2019",   index: 3, value: 3.0, roman: "III"),
        MyStruct("August 12, 2018", index: 5, value: 5.0, roman: "V"),
        MyStruct("June 1, 2018",    index: 4, value: 4.0, roman: "IV"),
        MyStruct("July 18, 2018",   index: 1, value: 1.0, roman: "I"),
        MyStruct("May 4, 2018",     index: 2, value: 2.0, roman: "II")
    ]
    let sorted = data.sorted(by: { $0.date < $1.date })
    sorted.forEach({ print("\($0.index): \($0.roman): \($0.value): \($0.dateString)")})
```

**Result:**

```
2: II: 2.0: May 4, 2018
4: IV: 4.0: June 1, 2018
1: I: 1.0: July 18, 2018
5: V: 5.0: August 12, 2018
3: III: 3.0: June 12, 2019
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. I used the `struct` and it works perfectly 